# Unable to remotely connect to my Hostinger database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having a problem connecting to my database remotely. I'm trying to interact with my database via a java program and the connection doesn't work. I also tried to connect via "LibreOffice Base" and it doesn't work either. I'll give you my manipulations:

[Step 1: I create a DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxRm3.png)

[Step 2: I enable remote access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksn4R.png)

[Step 3: I set my Java App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIAd1.png)

And when run I get this error:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I contacted the support and they told me that the error came from my site and that I had to modify the default.php file (I don't have a website for the moment), they told me that they didn't know anything about development and directed me to you.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: HI Hexas.  Start by creating a local database and getting your program to connect to that and do some simple operation like reading a line from a table.  Then try the remote connection.  Also, post your default.php file.  Also... Hostinger should be able to provide you with a sample program that does work, even if it's not in the same programming language.  Go back to them and beat your shoe on the table, like Khrushchev, get their attention.  Then try to get their sample to work.

Comment: @ssimm Thanks for your answer, I tried with a local database and it works very well.

The default.php: https://www.sendspace.com/file/y2caly

Also I tried to connect to the database directly from a script hosted on the site and it works... so the problem is really Honstinger related.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem on my own. All I had to do was disable NordVPN.

I don't know if it's because I'm using particular DNS (cloudfare) or if it's using a VPN but the problem is fixed.

Sincerely